# Passing a const value when connecting to slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have many signals in the same object and i want to connect them to a single slot while passing a const when connecting. To be specific, I would like to do something like this:

```
connect (obj, SIGNAL(sig()), obj2, SLOT(sl(1))) ;
connect (obj, SIGNAL(sig()), obj2, SLOT(sl(2))) ;
connect (obj, SIGNAL(sig()), obj2, SLOT(sl(3))) ;
connect (obj, SIGNAL(sig()), obj2, SLOT(sl(4))) ;
```

Is there any way I can do this?
Since all the signals come from the same object I can't use QSignalMapper.
Any suggestions/workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate QSignalMapper for each connection.  Not very efficient, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try as

```
connect (obj, SIGNAL(sig(int)), obj2, SLOT(sl(int))) ;
```

Since when using signal & slots, both should have same parameters. So we can emit any signal with the any value. The value emitted by the signal is automatically passed to the slot.